# Windows Authentication in Javascript html

Tags: javascript, html, activex

Hi i tried to fetch the username from the IIS windows Authentication On blog i found following code

```
var WinNetwork = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network")
```

but it's not supporting on chrome. please help me on to acheive this html javascript

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately ActiveX object doesn't support other browsers than Internet Explorer.

You need to try server side code.

Comment: WAFFLE is plugin, which provides these solutions but depends on which platform you use .

Comment: How am just using html page?